# Refund a Sale in Paypal Rest API caught an INTERNAL SERVICE ERROR 500 using C#

Tags: c#, paypal

I'm trying to refund a sale in a Paypal.
I'm using Paypal REST API.

Here's my sample code:

```
APIContext apiContext = APiConfig();

Sale sale = Sale.Get(apiContext, "0D952456WY462504J");
Amount refundAmount = new Amount();
refundAmount.total = "0.01";
refundAmount.currency = currency;

Refund refund = new Refund();
refund.amount = refundAmount;

var newRefund = sale.Refund(apiContext, refund);

response = new PaypalResponse() {
       amount = newRefund.amount,
       create_time = Convert.ToDateTime(newRefund.create_time),
       update_time = Convert.ToDateTime(newRefund.update_time),
       state = newRefund.state,
       parent_payment = newRefund.parent_payment,
       id = newRefund.id
       };
```

Getting error on this line: "var newRefund = sale.Refund(apiContext, refund);"
It said that: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Can anyone answer this? Thanks!

Comment: Solved! Previous version of paypal sdk has a bug on Sale.Refund. If anyone has the same issue just update your Paypal SDK to the latest version(1.2.1)

Thank you @EdSF :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the .Net SDK, update it to the latest version (just released, IINM version **1.2.1**), there [was a bug](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues/62) in `Sale.Refund` and was [fixed](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/commit/eb98199c1fc51cd4dde5bc4d3d0b199090e2d3df)

Hth....